# Validating deployment yaml with custom set of rules

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to validate the deployment yaml based on certain rules on EKS.
Like if there is no field of nodeselector then kubernetes should reject that deployment.

Comment: You want to so static check or dynamic check ?

Comment: dynamic check will be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is a clear fit for the [Open Policy Agent](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa).

You need to deploy it as a [Validating Web Hook](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa) to your K8s cluster and configure [Rego Rules](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/) to define the K8s Yaml format you want to mandate.

Comment: Any particular reason you unaccepted my answer?